# How to add date-time from CSV file to x axis using python (numpy)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have CSV file with 3 columns. What I am trying to do is to plot the CH_1 column with the Time column as the x-axis. However, the x-axis does not appear? Please, Could you help me?

my data from CSV file (output2.csv) is:

```
Time             CH_1       h
4/4/2019 13:32  249.8675    3
4/4/2019 13:32  249.8675    5
4/4/2019 13:32  249.8675    0
4/4/2019 13:33  249.8675    
4/4/2019 13:33  249.8675    5
4/4/2019 13:33  249.8675    4
4/4/2019 13:33  249.8675    
4/4/2019 13:34  247.248     6
4/4/2019 13:34  249.8675    6
```

```
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

style.use('ggplot')
data = np.genfromtxt('output2.csv', delimiter=',', names=True)
x = data['Time']
y = data['CH_1']
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: See [mcve]. Your data does not contain any names.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited it.

Comment: And the delimiter? Put yourself in the position of someone reading the question. Would they be able to reproduce this or not?